# Firemonkey - iOS File Sharing

Tags: firemonkey

There is a way to share a file "sample.xyz" to a social network FB, W... from iOS ?

The file is created native by my application.

I try with ShareSheet and work nice but i cannot attach file, only pictures and texts.

Any help will be highly appreciated !

Comment: What kind of file do you have in mind? And do you know of another application that can do this? According to this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios/ nothing but images and videos can be shared.

Comment: Is a native file created by this app.

Comment: The file should be exported/imported (using same app) between users.

I already done with email but it will be easiear to share with Whatsapp, Fb...etc